# Gremlin: How to efficiently find "roots" in directed acyclic graph?

Tags: java, gremlin, graph-databases, tinkerpop3

I'm trying to write a gremlin query that efficiently solves the "confluent rivers" problem (for a lack of a better name, maybe there is one in graph theory?). Here's an example:

[image]

The task: given one of the root nodes, deliver a map containing the IDs of downstream nodes as keys, with all of their river root IDs (i.e. the end nodes reached by going all paths upwards again from the current node) as values.

For instance, in the example graph above, and for root node 0, the result should be:

```json
{
 "0": ["0"],
 "1": ["0", "4"],
 "2": ["0", "5", "8"],
 "3": ["0", "4", "5", "8"],
 "6": ["0", "4"]
}
```

I'm particularly worried here about walking paths multiple times. For example, after calculating the roots of "2", I'd like to reuse that result for computing the roots of its downstream node "3".

Any clues how that might work for a large directed acyclic graph?

Answer (score 1):

Given your diagram we can create the following graph.

```
g.addV('0').as('0').
  addV('1').as('1').
  addV('2').as('2').
  addV('3').as('3').
  addV('4').as('4').
  addV('5').as('5').
  addV('6').as('6').
  addV('7').as('7').
  addV('8').as('8').
  addE('link').from('0').to('1').
  addE('link').from('0').to('2').
  addE('link').from('1').to('6').
  addE('link').from('1').to('3').
  addE('link').from('2').to('3').
  addE('link').from('4').to('1').
  addE('link').from('5').to('7').
  addE('link').from('7').to('2').
  addE('link').from('8').to('7').iterate()
```

The query below starts at '0' and finds all the leaf nodes and then works backwards to find all the roots. The output does not include the starting node ('0') but if necessary the query can be tweaked to include that.

```
gremlin>  g.V().hasLabel('0').
......1>        repeat(out()).emit().
......2>        until(__.not(out())).dedup().
......3>        group().
......4>          by(label()).
......5>          by(repeat(__.in('link')).
......6>             until(__.not(__.in('link'))).
......7>             label().dedup().
......8>             fold())

==>[1:[0,4],2:[0,8,5],3:[0,8,4,5],6:[0,4]]
```

If ordering is important the query can be updated to order the lists.

UPDATED

Adding an extra example that also includes '0' as a key in the results.

```
gremlin>  g.V().hasLabel('0').
......1>        emit().repeat(out()).
......2>        until(__.not(out())).dedup().
......3>        group().
......4>          by(label()).
......5>          by(coalesce(
......6>              repeat(__.in('link')).
......7>              until(__.not(__.in('link'))).
......8>              label().dedup().
......9>              fold()))

==>[0:[],1:[0,4],2:[0,5,8],3:[0,4,5,8],6:[0,4]]
```

Comment: Thank you for your efforts! The query in your answer is really smart and I learned a new trick or two. It does produce the correct result. However, if I enable the logging on the vertices and edges being loaded by this gremlin query, it's clear that some of the path e.g. 2 -> 7 -> 8 and 2 -> 7 -> 5 have been resolved multiple times by gremlin (once for evaluating the map value of 2, and once for map value of 3). Is there a way around this? I thought about using barriers or similar tools.

Comment: Are you seeing a performance impact from this? To some extent the amount of work done executing a query can depend on the amount of optimization an implementation is able to do.

Comment: I don't think a general purpose traversal optimizer would ever be able to figure this out on its own because the path caching we're talking about is only possible for directed acyclic graph topology. TinkerPop 2 had a memoization feature which seems to be discontinued in TP3. I was thinking about bulk traversers but I don't see how to apply them here. It's more of a "dynamic programming" thing we'd need where the solution is built incrementally. Every downstream node has the set union of the roots of its upstream nodes, and the query utilize this fact yet. Using a sack, perhaps?

Comment: There is nothing in TinkerPop 3.x that is quite like the old `memoize` but traversal bulking performs a similar task and uses less memory.